# Jquery: Máscara não apaga

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Não estou conseguindo digitar nada dentro de um campo textbox que coloquei máscara de data, ele não me deixa apagar e nem digitar por cima, ele fica sempre 11/11/1111

Segue abaixo os códigos que coloquei:

Tudo que estou importando:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JavascriptInsano.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/funcao_validate_data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Nessa mesma página tem o Input:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DataInicio, "Data de Início", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DataInicio, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Agora segue o javascript que faz com a função:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#DataInicio").mask("11/11/1111",{placeholder:" "});
});

jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#DataTermino").mask("11/11/1111");
});
```

Comment: No site do plugin você entendera melhor seu funcionamento, mas acho que o Fernando Medeiros ja resolveu seu problema abaixo. http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string da máscara deve estar no seguinte formato, no caso de ser um número deve ser utilizado o número 9 como representação, seu erro está em usar o número 1.

```
$("#DataTermino").mask('99/99/9999');
```